# How do you set the number of decimals displayed in a cell with google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm copying a template where the original value is a division by zero, so I can't change manually the number of decimal digits displayed. Is there a way to modify this parameter with a google script command?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of the custom function that does that. Custom functions can be referenced in each spreadsheet cell, but you can use the same approach in functions that write to range of cells:

```
function MYFUNCTION(a, b, numOfDigits){

return (a / b).toFixed(numOfDigits);

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that. I need to change the setting of the cell, as the value is calculated via division and could change

Comment: Could you please go into greater detail about what you are copying and what outcome you expect? Division by zero gives you Infinity

Comment: Of course: The original cell (with a division by zero) is in a template page which doesn't host any data. When it gets copied, its cells of reference for the division also get filled, so the resilt is no longer invalid. However, I can't change the number of displayed decimals on the template because it doesn't show a valid number.